# Using image with rectangle drawn over it in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, draw

I'm using `cv2.rectangle` in python to draw a box on my image.
`image1` has already been loaded correctly.
Then I use this code:

```
cv2.rectangle(image1, (10, 10), (100, 100), (255,0,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img', image1)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
```

I get errors no matter what I do with the image after using `cv2.rectangle`. How can I retrieve or use the image on which I drew the rectangle?

### Edit

Correction, I get this error *on* using cv2.rectangle, not after it.

Comment: sounds like image1 is not a numpy array

Comment: I just printed out its type and it said: *<type 'numpy.ndarray'>*

Comment: out of ideas then, sorry.

Comment: sounds like the dimension of the array is the issue?  print len(image1)

Answer (score 2):

Heh, several years late to help the original poster, but I just hit this problem myself and didn't have control over the image source (so `cv2.imread` wasn't a great solution for me - I'd've had to have written the image back to disk first).

I was able to proceed with `image = image.copy()`.

Not sure what the root cause was - an equality check showed every value of the array was equivalent, and the array was the correct type.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('<path to image>')
cv2.rectangle(im, (10, 10), (100, 100), (255,0,0), 2)
im = cv2.cv.fromarray(im)
cv2.cv.SaveImage("<path you want to save image in>", im)
```

Comment: Just edited my question. I realized I'm getting the error by simply using *cv2.rectangle*, not on trying to use it.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error. Maybe try this before the rectangle line: image1 = numpy.asarray(image1)

Comment: Just tried that, but I'm still getting the same issue. Do you think it might have to do with me running 32-bit Anaconda/Spyder on a 64-bit Windows?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so. Maybe try reinstalling opencv? http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Comment: Not sure, but I would guess so. You could also try ipython, which is available via that link.

Comment: It's working for me on linux (Ubuntu) with Spyder. OpenCV version '2.4.7'

Comment: I read my file like this, if it makes a difference; *image1 = color.rgb2gray(io.imread("PATH-TO-FILE"))*

Comment: yes, the problem was the way I was reading the file. now it's reading and drawing rectangles without errors, when I read it using *cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE)*

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be caused by the version of numpy. Version 1.6.2 seems to cause this bug, but this issue is not present in 1.9.2, just upgrade it:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Tested on Debian 7.8 (kern 3.2) and Debian 8.0 (kern 4.2) for OpenCV 2.4.9