# OpenCV - cv2.floodFill() error in python

Tags: python, opencv, flood-fill

I got this error while using `cv2.floodfill()`:

[image]

My code:

```
    ormap = np.bitwise_or(label,detmap)
    mask = np.zeros((image_size+2,imagesize+2),np.uint8)
    for y in range(image_size):
        for x in range(image_size):
            if label[y,x]>0:
                cv2.floodFill(ormap,mask,(y,x),0)
```

I tried

1. `ormap.copy()` to a new array but it does not work
2. used `cv2.cv.fromarray()` but it says 'array type not supported'.

I am using OpenCV  2.4.11 and numpy 1.11.0
Any other suggestions?

Comment: What versions of OpenCV and Numpy are you seeing this with? BTW, `(y,x)` is in the wrong order -- the arrays are indexed row-first, but regular coordinates still should be `(x,y)`. Also, please don't insert text as images (I mean that error message).

Comment: Sure.I use opencv 2.4.8 and numpy 1.8.2

Comment: Oh, I see, those versions are about 2 years old -- OpenCV is now at 2.4.12, numpy at 1.11.0. Based on [similar reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723369/using-image-with-rectangle-drawn-over-it-in-python), this looks like a bug in one of the libraries that has since been fixed.

Comment: I upgrade to OpenCV to 2.4.11 and numpy to 1.11.0, same error, any other suggestions?

Comment: Interesting. One of the suggestions I've seen was to convert to python list (using `tolist()`) and then create a new `np.array` from this list. This should make an array that opencv should understand. Just to be sure, what are the dimensions (shape) of `ormap`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by performing the following change:

```
ormap = np.bitwise_or(label,detmap).astype(uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another **opencv floodfill function** that may help Incase your ROI is segmented as a white blob. Assume you have used Otsu thresholding:

```
def flood_fill_binary(binary):
    hh = binary.shape[0]
    ww = binary.shape[1]
    xx = 10
    yy = 10
    black = [0,0,0]
    binary = cv2.copyMakeBorder(binary,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=black)
    im_floodfill = binary.copy()
    h, w = binary.shape[:2]
    mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
    cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255)
    im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
    im_out = binary | im_floodfill_inv
    crop_og = im_out[yy:yy+hh,xx:xx+ww]
    return crop_og
```